# Cannot reach a SSL site using Internet Explorer 8

Tags: ssl, internet-explorer-8

I cannot open a website using Internet Explorer 8, but can using either Firefox or Chrome. Under IE the page doesn't even open (as if it cannot be found).

My problem is that the app I'm using to create the SSL connection is coded on the IEAK API. I'm only using other browsers as a troubleshooting measure. I have gone through the whole procedure as listed through http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/968089, but obviously that doesn't work. The same problem is happening on fifteen other computers. For other technical reasons, I am not permitted to upgrade IE either. There were all working until the certificate expired in the middle of March. The certificate was renewed, but connectivity never recovered. It may have something to do with the way IE8 handles the certificate especially around the way expired certificates and renewals work.

Is this a known issue with IE8? And is there a patch perhaps?

Comment: If you can open it up in Chrome which uses the Windows Certificate Store then its not a certificate problem but a IE configuration problem.  The default configuration settings for which versions of SSL will be accepted by Firefox and Chrome are different than IE8.  Without more knowledge about the certificate itself it will be tough to suggest solutions.

Comment: On further investigation it looks like the site has recently changed it's certificate. Prior to the change it worked without issue, but all of the clients stopped when the certificate was changed last week. New clients have no problem, it is all the old clients that were installed prior to the certificate being changed. IE8 seems to have a problem with enrolling the use of new certificate, or something is lingering in a certificate cache.

Comment: Update your question

Answer (score 1):

This might be due do the use of [SNI (Server Name Indication)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), which is often required by todays site, like all sites protected by the free HTTPS offer from Cloudflare. This might also be due to missing ciphers etc.  More information might be given if you provide the URL.

If you are not able to upgrade the OS/browser or use a different browser or change the server settings there is probably nothing you can do.